# SSE different client receive messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, server-sent-events

Im writing a messenger with Spring MVC , and I want that user which online could receive message from server. Best solution that I found its SSE , founded this method , but how server must know which user should receive this message , if all of active(online) user subscribed to this method ?

```
@GetMapping("/stream-sse-mvc")
public SseEmitter streamSseMvc() {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    ExecutorService sseMvcExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    sseMvcExecutor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
                SseEventBuilder event = SseEmitter.event()
                  .data("SSE MVC - " + LocalTime.now().toString())
                  .id(String.valueOf(i))
                  .name("sse event - mvc");
                emitter.send(event);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            emitter.completeWithError(ex);
        }
    });
    return emitter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSE are kindof a one-way street. For a 2-way communication I think you'd need something else like web sockets, but I suppose you could do the following:

1. When the client makes first contact, pass its ID to the server.
2. The server keep track of that id and all the messages it has sent to that client in its send loop. I don't think this guarantees that the client received the message, but maybe it's good enough.
3. If you get an exception (usually because the connection is closed), the client probably didn't receive the message.

ANOTHER OPTION:

I suppose you could also have the client record all the messages it receives and report them either one by one upon receipt or later as a batch. However, I start to wonder at that point if there aren't existing syncing solutions that would handle this for you.